# mysql2.so: libmysqlclient_r.so.15: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, mysql2, ruby-on-rails-2, libmysql

I am trying to run a Rails two app with Ubuntu 10.04 server, sphinx, myql2 version 0.2.7 and percona server 5.5 (Myslql 5.5). mysql2 in irb works ok, I can connect to the db. this rails 2 app is working in another Centos server with MySql 5.1. When I run:

```
script/server -e production
```

I get:

> mysql2.so: libmysqlclient_r.so.15: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

here are the libs I have:

```
# ls -l /usr/lib |grep sql
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 10581008 2011-11-18 16:51 libmysqlclient.a
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       16 2011-12-10 05:48 libmysqlclient_r.a -> libmysqlclient.a
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       20 2011-12-10 05:48 libmysqlclient.so -> libmysqlclient.so.16
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       29 2011-12-10 06:01 libmysqlclient.so.15 -> /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.so.16
-rw-r--r--  1 root root     7332 2011-11-18 16:44 libmysqlservices.a
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   562520 2010-02-08 06:59 libsqlite3.a
-rw-r--r--  1 root root      973 2010-02-08 06:59 libsqlite3.la
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       19 2011-12-07 17:15 libsqlite3.so -> libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       19 2011-03-09 18:43 libsqlite3.so.0 -> libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   528668 2010-02-08 06:59 libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root     4096 2011-12-10 05:47 mysql
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Can you located libmysqlclient_r.so? if found, symlink to this

Comment: For CentOS, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10529401/libmysqlclient-so-15-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-directory

Answer (score 102, accepted):

If you encounter this error again after upgrading to 12.04 (or for people arriving here after googling the title of this page after upgrading to 12.04), the following worked for me:

```
gem uninstall mysql2
gem install mysql2
```

This will recompile the gem using libmysqlclient18, and worked for me.

Comment: Much better idea to reinstall with the latest lib than try to reinstall the old one.

Comment: or it can be do_mysql
`gem uninstall do_mysql &&  gem install do_mysql`

Comment: I did 'bundle exec gem uninstall mysql2' followed by 'bundle' from the rails application directory.

Comment: I recently upgraded my ubuntu to 16.04 and this is what I had to do to make my app work +1

Comment: For Ubuntu  20.04, I must run `apt install libmysqlclient21 libmysqlclient-dev` before `gem` command.

Comment: @giorgio Your comment did the trick and brought me out of the frustrating time I spent for hours. Thank You

Answer (score 9):

You need to install the development libraries.  Try

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient20-dev
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient19-dev
```

Answer (score 2):

Install the mysql client libraries: `apt-get install libmysqlclient16`

Comment: done and I get: libmysqlclient16 is already the newest version.

Answer (score 2):

I had this error with mysql-python and solved this using pip:

```
pip uninstall mysql-python
pip install mysql-python
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option that has not been mentioned here, but has been answered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36796167/upgraded-to-ubuntu-16-04-now-mysql-python-dependencies-are-broken/36835229#comment70103396_36835229). Is that you have to install `MySQL-python` with the `--no-binary` option. This question is a lot easier to find, so I'm adding the answer here for reference:

First uninstall your current version of `MySQL-python`:

```sh
pip uninstall MySQL-python
```

Then install `MySQL-python` with the `--no-binary` parameter:

```sh
pip install --no-binary MySQL-python MySQL-python
```

Answer (score 1):

After updated to Ubuntu 19.10. I got the error:

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: libmysqlclient.so.20: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

**Solution:**

1) activate your virtualenv

2) (yourvirtualenv) `pip uninstall mysqlclient`

3) (yourvirtualenv) `pip install mysqlclient`

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Ubuntu/Debian, the correct solution is to install libmariadb-dev-compat and rebuild (with MariaDB 10.3+).