# Linux - Dependency libmysqlclient.so.15 not found

Tags: linux, dependencies, centos, rpm, libmysql

I start the instalation, now i receive a error for file dependencies

see:

```
root@ca [~/sitebuilder]# rpm -Uhv updates/*.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
libmysqlclient.so.15()(64bit) is needed by php5sb-5.2.1-10swsoft.x86_64
libmysqlclient.so.15(libmysqlclient_15)(64bit) is needed by php5sb-5.2.1-10swsoft.x86_64
```

How to install a libmysqlclient.so.15 dependence on centos?

Thanks.

Comment: could you build this application from source?

Comment: hi, is a server with cpanel, and I already have mysql.

I need to know how to fix these dependencies ...

Any other tips?

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered this problem before.

I checked libmysqlclient.so version, it's libmysqlclient.so.16 but not libmysqlclient.so.15.

so I used MySQL-shared-compat rpm package to solve this.

run:

```
#rpm -qp --provides MySQL-shared-compat-5.1.47-1.rhel5.x86_64.rpm
MySQL-shared 
libmysqlclient.so.12()(64bit) 
libmysqlclient.so.14()(64bit) 
libmysqlclient.so.14(libmysqlclient_14)(64bit) 
libmysqlclient.so.15()(64bit) 
libmysqlclient.so.15(libmysqlclient_15)(64bit) 
libmysqlclient.so.16()(64bit) 
libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit) 
libmysqlclient_r.so.12()(64bit) 
libmysqlclient_r.so.14()(64bit) 
libmysqlclient_r.so.14(libmysqlclient_14)(64bit) 
libmysqlclient_r.so.15()(64bit) 
libmysqlclient_r.so.15(libmysqlclient_15)(64bit) 
libmysqlclient_r.so.16()(64bit) 
libmysqlclient_r.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit) 
MySQL-shared-compat = 5.1.47-1.rhel5
```

Comment: Hi Lai,

I ran the command on my server and was equal to the log above, but still keep getting the error dependence problems, know what else can I do?

Answer (score 1):

The missing package was Mysql-Shared-compat.
found it here http://mirrors.dedipower.com/www.mysql.com/Downloads/MySQL-5.5/MySQL-shared-compat-5.5.23-1.sles11.x86_64.rpm

Answer (score 0):

You can try to find the right package by the following command:

```
$ sudo yum whatprovides libmysqlclient.so.15
libmysqlclient15-5.0.95-5.w5.i386
libmysqlclient15-devel-5.0.95-5.w5.i386
cpanel-mysql-libs-5.0.96-1.cp1136.i386 : The shared libraries required for MySQL clients
```

then:

```
$ sudo yum reinstall WHATEVER_THE_PACKAGE_NAME_IS
```

You may double check the package name by doing `yum search package_name`.

If not found, you may try to fix your yum repositories e.g. by configuring [Webtatic Yum](http://webtatic.com/projects/yum-repository/) Repository.

To set up the repository, install the webtatic-release RPM:

Webtatic EL6 for CentOS/RHEL 6:

```
rpm -Uvh http://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el6/latest.rpm
```

Webtatic EL5.1 for CentOS/RHEL 5:

```
rpm -Uvh http://repo.webtatic.com/yum/el5/latest.rpm
```

Webtatic 5 for CentOS/RHEL 5:

```
rpm -Uvh http://repo.webtatic.com/yum/centos/5/latest.rpm
```

and repeat the search/reinstall process again.

---

If you're running **cPanel**, you may try to run the following script:

```
/scripts/check_cpanel_rpms --fix
```

If won't help, remove the broken package e.g. `rpm -e cpanel-mysql-5.0.96-1.cp1136` and run the check command again.

If still doesn't work, another thing could be to recompile your Apache (only if your LAMP is broken) by:

```
/scripts/easyapache
```

---

**Related**

**CentOS**

- [libmysqlclient.so.15: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10529401/libmysqlclient-so-15-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-directory/22282382)
- [Linux - Dependency libmysqlclient.so.15 not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8889603/linux-dependency-libmysqlclient-so-15-not-found/11031075)

**Ubuntu**

- [mysql2.so: libmysqlclient_r.so.15: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8456300/mysql2-so-libmysqlclient-r-so-15-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file)

Answer (score 0):

Like the answer of @lai

I install the  **MySQL-shared-compat-5.1.47-1.rhel5.x86_64.rpm**. But it didn't work.

And then I install the **MySQL-shared-5.1.47-1.rhel5.x86_64.rpm**. It worked!

I hope this can help you. Good luck :)