# libmysqlclient.so.15: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, apache, centos, passenger

All Rails applications are working just fine until today. I am not sure if someone changes the settings on this machine. However does anyone know what could be the fix for this?

Details:

1. Centos 5.5
2. Apache
3. Passenger
4. Rails 3.0.x
5. MySql 5.0.77

Error details:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Ubuntu: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8456300/mysql2-so-libmysqlclient-r-so-15-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file/22257336

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay this saves the day.

```
wget -O /usr/lib64/libmysqlclient.so.15 http://files.directadmin.com/services/es_5.0_64/libmysqlclient.so.15
chmod 755 /usr/lib64/libmysqlclient.so.15
ldconfig
```

Comment: Oh, i must add my comment here. Please use this solution only for private weekend hacks, it is **never** okay to download binaries/shared libraries from unknown resources;

Answer (score 1):

You can try to find the right package by the following command:

```
$ sudo yum whatprovides libmysqlclient.so.15
libmysqlclient15-5.0.95-5.w5.i386
libmysqlclient15-devel-5.0.95-5.w5.i386
cpanel-mysql-libs-5.0.96-1.cp1136.i386 : The shared libraries required for MySQL clients
```

then:

```
$ sudo yum reinstall WHATEVER_THE_PACKAGE_NAME_IS
```

You may double check the package name by doing `yum search package_name`.

If not found, you may try to fix your yum repositories e.g. by configuring [Webtatic Yum](http://webtatic.com/projects/yum-repository/) Repository.

To set up the repository, install the webtatic-release RPM:

Webtatic EL6 for CentOS/RHEL 6:

```
rpm -Uvh http://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el6/latest.rpm
```

Webtatic EL5.1 for CentOS/RHEL 5:

```
rpm -Uvh http://repo.webtatic.com/yum/el5/latest.rpm
```

Webtatic 5 for CentOS/RHEL 5:

```
rpm -Uvh http://repo.webtatic.com/yum/centos/5/latest.rpm
```

and repeat the search/reinstall process again.

---

If you're running **cPanel**, you may try to run the following script:

```
/scripts/check_cpanel_rpms --fix
```

If won't help, remove the broken package e.g. `rpm -e cpanel-mysql-5.0.96-1.cp1136` and run the check command again.

If still doesn't work, another thing could be to recompile your Apache (only if your LAMP is broken) by:

```
/scripts/easyapache
```