# CentOS: Lib for mysqlclient

Tags: mysql, gcc, centos

I am try to compile an old project at a new machine (CentOS 7) with gcc.
The last the linker is missing is libmysqlclient.

But I can not find it in my CentOS Repos (base, updates, extras).

Anyone have an idea in which package it is?
I already have installed mysql, mysql-devel and mysql-libs.

Thanks!

Cheers,
Chris

edit:

```
rpm -Uhv updates/*.rpm
Fehler: Datei von "glob" nicht gefunden: updates/*.rpm
```

means: error: file not found

```
yum whatprovides libmysqlclient.so.15
Geladene Plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror2.hs-esslingen.de
 * extras: mirror.nextlayer.at
 * updates: mirror.softaculous.com
No matches found
```

Comment: `yum whatprovides libmysqlclient.so.15`

Comment: "No matches found".
Do I miss a repository??

Comment: Hmm... try this than: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8889603/linux-dependency-libmysqlclient-so-15-not-found

Comment: error: File not found by glob: updates/*.rpm

Comment: what did you try exactly?

Comment: I edited my question with the commands/output.

Comment: Ahh understood. You need to download the .rpm file/files from online. Google should be able to find them for you. Than you do `rpm -Uhv rpm_file_here` this should add it to yum. To look for examples try googling `add epel repo to centos` this should get you started.

Comment: read through this page: https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/install-epel-and-additional-repositories-on-centos-and-red-hat/ and you will get a better idea how this works

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what of the following 2 actions did the trick.

- yum install mysqlclient.so.18
- I corrected the link from /usr/lib64/mysql/mysqlclient.so to /usr/lib64/mysqlclient.so

But I can compile now :-)
Thanks for help!