# Rails not working after updating Ubuntu from 10.04 to 14.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, updates, ubuntu-14.04

I had installed Rails in Ubuntu 10.04. And had some applications up and running. But after updating the Ubuntu to 14.04, rails apps are not working.

When I try to start my Rails app (As $rails server), am getting the following warning and help:

```
bin/rails:6: warning: already initialized constant APP_PATH
/home/razor/rails_projs/simple_cms/bin/rails:6: warning: previous definition of APP_PATH was here
Usage: rails COMMAND [ARGS]

The most common rails commands are:
 generate    Generate new code (short-cut alias: "g")
 console     Start the Rails console (short-cut alias: "c")
 server      Start the Rails server (short-cut alias: "s")
 dbconsole   Start a console for the database specified in config/database.yml
         (short-cut alias: "db")
 new         Create a new Rails application. "rails new my_app" creates a
         new application called MyApp in "./my_app"

In addition to those, there are:
 application  Generate the Rails application code
 destroy      Undo code generated with "generate" (short-cut alias: "d")
 plugin new   Generates skeleton for developing a Rails plugin
 runner       Run a piece of code in the application environment (short-cut alias: "r")

All commands can be run with -h (or --help) for more information.
```

Comment: While updating ubuntu to 14.04, it asked if I want to remove some obsolete packages. And chose Yes, does that matter?

Answer (score 0):

That happened to me when I mistakenly tried to run rails server from outside of the app directory and again from inside a gem/engine directory. Can you confirm that you are inside your main app? It looks like you are, if your app name is simple_cms.

If so, then what do you get when you run

```
type rails
```

and

```
which rails
```

Its weird that it gives you the option to create an app from within an app, that isn't possible. Which version of rails do you have installed?

Comment: yeah, am running rails server from inside my app. And output of the commands are as follows:
$type rails 
    `rails is hashed (/home/razor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/rails)`
$which rails
    `/home/razor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/rails`

Comment: Can you give me the rails version too? I think the command is rails -v and also the version of rails your app is using. Could you also try and create a new rails app and run rails server from within that.

Comment: Rails version : `4.1.6`
Tried with new app, even that is giving the same result.

Answer (score 0):

[This link](http://www.stackoverflow.com/a/10369022/1129470), helped me with the problem. 
I had to uninstall mysql2 gem and then reinstall it.

Commands I used

```
$gem uninstall mysql2
$gem install mysql2
```

Than everything was fine, could start server.