# Upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 now MySQL-python dependencies are broken

Tags: python, mysql, ubuntu, pip, ubuntu-16.04

I just upgraded my Ubuntu install to 16.04 and this seems to have broken my mysql dependencies in the MySQL-python package.

Here is my error message:

```
  File "/opt/monitorenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/__init__.py", line 386, in create_engine
return strategy.create(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/monitorenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 75, in create
dbapi = dialect_cls.dbapi(**dbapi_args)
  File "/opt/monitorenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/mysqldb.py", line 92, in dbapi
return __import__('MySQLdb')
  File "/opt/monitorenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    import _mysql
ImportError: libmysqlclient.so.18: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

So basically the import_mysql is looking for an `so` file that doesn't exist because in Ubuntu 16.04, I have `libmysqlclient20` installed.
And libmysqlclient18 is not available.
As far as I am aware  (or at least I believe) my python libraries are up to date with the latest versions.

(I tried running `pip install --upgrade mysql-python` which indicated it was up to date).

Do you guys have any suggestions ?

Comment: Create a new virtual environment from your requirements.txt file. If you don't have any: `pip freeze > requirements.txt`.

Comment: I am getting the same error as before, I'm afraid

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I ended up finding the solution to my problems with `pip install --no-binary MySQL-python MySQL-python`
as stated in this thread : [Python's MySQLdb can’t find libmysqlclient.dylib with Homebrewed MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34536914/pythons-mysqldb-can-t-find-libmysqlclient-dylib-with-homebrewed-mysql)

Comment: Wish I could upvote this more than once. In the past week I've run into this problem multiple times. The answer is not too easy to find unfortunately.

Comment: For those stumbling along hitting a `no such option: --no-binary` error: make sure to upgrade your version of pip first!

Answer (score 47):

Thank for Largaroth. If you use `mysqlclient` on Ubuntu 16.04 and have error:

`ImportError: libmysqlclient.so.18: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

You can fix:

```shell
sudo -H pip uninstall mysqlclient

sudo -H pip install --no-binary mysqlclient mysqlclient
```

Comment: "MySQL-python" was reported as already installed, so *this* answer was the one which corrected the problem.

Comment: Thanks.  This and the above fixed it for me.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue. I uninstalled and reinstalled MySQL-python:

```
pip uninstall MySQL-python
pip install MySQL-python
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue on updating to stretch.  To fix it I updated my requirements.txt:

mysqlclient==1.4.2.post1

So either update that manually or pip install --upgrade mysqlclient

Comment: thanks, this (--upgrade option) fixed my issue after upgrade from ubuntu 19.04 to 19.10

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that I was using wheelhouse from old OS.

The problem was solved when I uninstalled/installed the package or updated wheelhouse...

From docs:

http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/FAQ.html#importerror

> This means you have a version of MySQLdb compiled against one version of MySQL, and are now trying to run it against a different version. The shared library version tends to change between major releases.
>
> Solution: Rebuilt MySQLdb, or get the matching version of MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Steps:

1. search mysql path

   which mysql

   O/p : /opt/mysql/
2. create Symbolic Links to usr/lib

   sudo ln -s /opt/mysql/lib/mysqlclient.so.20 /usr/lib

Note: mysqlclient.so.20 will be as per your version

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with python 3.6... when I used an environment with Python 3.5 it worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this on my virtual environment using django 2.2.7 and Ubuntu 19.10   by doing:

> pip3 uninstall mysqlclient
>
> pip3 install mysqlclient